# Start Activity in Adapter

Tags: android

I have `Start Activity` in `Adapter` class, I use this code but dose not work. I use `Recycler View` instead of list view.

How to correct this code?

```
public class CardViewDataAdapter_smiley extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardViewDataAdapter_smiley.ViewHolder> {
public String[] mDataset;
static public Context context;
public CardViewDataAdapter_smiley(String[] myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
}
public CardViewDataAdapter_smiley(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public CardViewDataAdapter_smiley.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                                int viewType) {
          View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.cardview_smiley, null);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    return viewHolder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    viewHolder.tvtinfo_text.setText(mDataset[position].toString());
    viewHolder.versionName = mDataset[position];
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.length;
}
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvtinfo_text;
    public String versionName;
    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        tvtinfo_text = (TextView) itemLayoutView
                .findViewById(R.id.cardview_title_smiley);
        itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,SMS_Smiley.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        itemLayoutView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), test text" + versionName,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}}
```

Comment: what does not work? do you have a stacktrace for us?

Comment: You have two constructors for CardViewDataAdapter_smiley in this which one you are using for creating adapter object?

Comment: *i use this code but dose not work*  : What not working ?

Comment: @Nag , I could not use so I wrote to the 2 to constructor
How do I open an activity inside the adapter?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK , i see simple example but i can't use it, so write 2 constructors. when click on Recycler view Force Close error

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK: tnx .first use this code but when running application with FC error, my main activity code is : mAdapter = new sms_card_smiley_Adapter(myDataset);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter); .

Comment: @Mohammad: see my answer use `OR` part for starting Activity

Comment: @Mohammad: Create adapter object as `mAdapter = new sms_card_smiley_Adapter(myDataset,YourCurrentActivityName.this);`

Comment: You pasted in the same two sentences twice without noticing. Others are not going to give your Q attention, if you obviously give  so little of it yourself. There should also be no distractions, no chit-chat (read help→tour), so leave away the begging from the question. Include an error message (edit the text, but never include *Edit* or similar) and/or input resp. expected output or a clear description of behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably `context` is `null` :

Use single constructor to pass String Array and Context :

```
public CardViewDataAdapter_smiley(String[] myDataset,Context context) {
            this.mDataset = myDataset;
             this.context = context;
  }
```

**OR**

with-out passing Context in constructor use `v.getContext()` to start Activity on Click:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),SMS_Smiley.class);
        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: tnx my dear friend, tnnnnnnnnnnnnx <3 . its ok